# Palindrome - Is it possible to make my code faster

Tags: performance, go

I have an ASCII-only string which is either already a palindrome, or else can be made a palindrome by removing one character. I need to determine whether it's already a palindrome, and if not, I need to find the index of the character that would need to be removed. For example, if the string is `'aaba'`, then it can be made into the palindrome `'aba'` by removing the first character, so I need to return `0`.

I have working code, but I am wondering if it is possible to make it faster, because I need to work with many long strings.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    )

func Palindrome(s string) bool {
    var l int = len(s)

    for i := 0; i < l / 2; i++ {
        if s[i] != s[l - 1 - i] {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true
}

func RemoveChar(s string, idx int) string {
    return s[0:idx-1] + s[idx:len(s)]
}

func findIdx(s string) int {
    if Palindrome(s) {
        return -1
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if Palindrome(RemoveChar(s, i + 1)) {
            return i
        }
    }

    return -2
}

func main() {
    var s string = "aabaab"
    fmt.Println(findIdx(s))
}
```

Comment: The vast majority of strings will return -2 because you can't make them a palindrome by removing just one letter. I would begin findIdX by first checking for cases where you can obviously return -2 without a more detailed check - for example if there are more than 2 characters which occur an odd number of times, you can return -2 straight away.

Comment: Your code only works for ASCII characters.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, I know exactly that there is one letter to remove and make it a palindrome

Comment: @peterSO, yes, I know.  it is ok in my case. the performance is issue

Comment: In that case, you just need to loop from 0 to length / 2. As soon you find an i where s[i] is different from s[length - 1 - i] you can return i. I won't try to write the code because I don't know go at all.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, did you said about Plaidrome() function or findIdx() function. If the first one - I have already use l/2. If the second one - it is not obvious for that I can use l/2. Thanks.

Comment: But what must "aabaa" give as a result? Because i think this is a Palindrome.

Comment: @Dippo, it returns -1.  It is palindrome.

Comment: @demas oops, i was wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake. Make findIdX loop from 0 to l/2. If s[i] differs from s[l - 1 - i] the answer will be either i or l - 1 - i so you can call Palindrome on RemoveChar(i + 1). If true, return i, if false return l - 1 - i. If the loop terminates without returning, return -1. This will be much quicker because Palindrome will only be called once.

Comment: Are you asking for the [Longest palindromic substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring)?

Comment: @peterSO, no, it is not lps

Comment: Ok, another try: the string "aabaab" returns 5 but if i look at the code, it must return 2 because "baab" is palindrome. If i keep removing the first letter what is in your criteria.

Comment: @Dippo For 'aabaab' the result is 5th -> 'aabaa' is a palindrom. To get 'baab' as you said we need to remove 2 letters, but we can remove only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much more efficient approach:

```
func findIdx(s string) int {
    for i := 0; i < len(s) / 2; i++ {
        if s[i] != s[len(s) - i - 1] {
             if isPalindrome(s[i+1:len(s)-i]) {
                 return i
             } else {
                 return len(s) - i - 1
             }
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

It just proceeds from the ends of the string until it finds a pair of bytes that *should* match, if the string were a palindrome, but that do not. It then knows that it will return the index of one of these two bytes, so it only needs to perform one "is this a palindrome?" check; and it doesn't need to use the `RemoveChar` function, since the "is this a palindrome?" check only needs to consider the middle portion of the string (that hasn't already been examined).

Answer (score 3):

This should be very slightly more efficient than ruakh's solution. You shouldn't have to use isPalindrome() to check that `s[i + 1:len(s) - i]` is a palindrome because it's quicker to check that `s[i:len(s) - i - 1]` is *not* a palindrome. In the solution below, in most cases j won't get very far at all before the function returns.

```
func findIdx(s string) int {
    var n int = len(s) 
    for i := 0; i < n / 2; i++ {
        if s[i] != s[n - i - 1] {
             for j := 0; ;j++ {
                 if s[i + j] != s[n - 2 - i - j] {
                     return i;
                 }
                 if s[i + j + 1] != s[n - 1 - i - j] {
                     return n - 1 - i; 
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```